# Circular/ Elliptical patch antenna design

Tags: rf, antenna, radiation

I am trying to design a circularly/elliptical polarised antenna like the one in the picture. My frequency is 915MHz, a dielectric constant of 4.4, the thickness of the substrate is 1.6mm, thickness of copper is 0.1mm. I know how to obtain the radius of the patch but how do you calculate the microstrip line feed size and the size of the substrate?

[image: Conventional RHCP antenna]

Comment: bad news: in your previous question, you showed us an aluminium disk planar circularly polarized antenna. Your patch antenna won't be that much smaller if you're just using \$\epsilon\$ of 4.4...

Comment: @MarcusMüller "Your patch antenna won't be that much smaller if you're just using ϵ of 4.4" I know this is easy for you to see but for me, it is not. Hence I need the formulae that will show me this to calculate the unknown in my questions. And I this question as nothing to do with the last question, hence I did not post the link in this question. The previous post was someone else work

Comment: I'm also a bit confused myself, because I honestly don't think the antenna in your picture is circularly polarized, so I'm sadly not the right one to ask.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I did some further research and the circular microstrip patch antenna's lowest mode is the TM11, the next higher-order mode is the TM21 which can be driven to produce circularly polarized radiation.

Comment: @Joey ufffff... it's been a while...  but says nothing about the antenna you can use to generate that, as far as I can see?

Comment: @MarcusMüller any chance you know of how to calculate the dimensions of the substrate, is there a formula, or is it based on the patch size? If so can you link a formula?

Comment: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/630298 simulated and optimized using the
electromagnetic software Ansoft HFSS must have cross slot having equal slot lengths

Comment: This geometry is suboptimal coupling dielectric to freespace as a 1 sided radial resonator with impedance transforming feed line.. The Maxwellian math geometry is not trivial

Comment: @MarcusMüller Firstly I do apologize. After a bit more research I understand the science by what you meant by a circular patch doesn't produce a circularly polarised antenna. I am going to post a new question which I think you will understand because it was what you were saying this whole time. I hope you can assist.